# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ':'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I get Error:error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ':'in visual studio

for the following cpp code. Can anyone explain why I get this error?

help appreciated thanks

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define UP '1';
#define DOWN '2';
#define RIGHT '3';
#define LEFT '4';

void main()
{
    char key ;
    char value = 'x';
    cout<<"Enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4"<< endl;
    cin>>key;
    switch(key)
    {
    case UP :
        cout<<"case UP"<<endl;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        cout<<"case DOWN"<<endl;
        break;
    case LEFT:
        cout<<"case LEFT"<<endl;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        cout<<"case RIGHT"<<endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you use `#include <iostream>` and `cout << ...`, you are not writing C; you are writing C++.  Please be careful about how you tag your questions (and remember that C and C++ are very different languages).

Comment: `void main()` isn't a valid signature.

Answer (score 3):

; after #define must not be present.

Comment: Related to why you can't put two preprocessors directives on the same line.

Comment: Not so much 'not needed' as 'must not be present'.

Answer (score 2):

don't put `;` after define statements

```
    #define UP '1'
    #define DOWN '2'
    #define RIGHT '3'
    #define LEFT '4'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `#define`s have semicolons at the end of them.  So once they're expanded, you have:

```
    switch(key){
        case '1';:
```

Get rid of the semicolons.  `#define`s don't need a semicolon; they end when the line does.

Answer (score 2):

You can read [this](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Define).

---

Don't use `;` after `#define`. For example, when you want to initialize a variable, you should use this method:

```
#define Max_number 10000
```

**Potential problems:**

```
#define Max_number 10000;    // this is an error
#define Max_number = 10000   // this is also an error
```

Sometimes you can use it as a function:

```
#include <iostream>
#define show(x) cout << #x << " is : " << x;
int main(){
    int number = 76;
    std:: show(number);
}
```